# how to use some libGDX libraries in a project

Tags: java, libgdx, proguard

How can build a libGDX project so that not all of its libraries can be used, the fact is that I want to create a lightweight game and I want to use the minimum number of libraries, or another option:  can i delete some unnecessary libraries of the libGDX project, using Proguard is not suitable since I have little experience with this utility

Comment: Just remove them from the build.gradle?

Comment: Proguard is the way to do this. It’s not hard to learn the basics. You likely don’t need to do any configuration since libGDX provides a configuration file, unless you are using reflection.